# interpreting the results of forecasting time series analysis

Tags: r, time-series

I conducted a time series analysis (daily prediction)

```
library(forecast)
library(lubridate)
ts <- read.csv("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/ts.csv",sep=";", dec=",")
msts <- msts(ts$Daily.admissions,seasonal.periods = c(7,365.25),start = decimal_date(as.Date("2012-04-01")))        
tbats <- tbats(msts)
sp <- predict(tbats,h=14)      
print(sp)
```

On output I get this results:

```
          Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
2016.2514       45.21749 36.49811 56.01815 32.58475 62.74312
2016.2541       34.10518 27.49301 42.30623 24.52838 47.41754
2016.2569       35.54743 28.62030 44.14975 25.51742 49.51612
2016.2596       45.46761 36.56616 56.53412 32.58241 63.44356
2016.2623       41.72907 33.52017 51.94655 29.84972 58.33152
2016.2651       40.60631 32.58185 50.60537 28.99699 56.85909
2016.2678       40.88003 32.76501 51.00319 29.14283 57.33981
2016.2706       43.02138 34.44556 53.73044 30.62078 60.43903
2016.2733       32.50043 25.99185 40.63741 23.09164 45.73916
2016.2760       33.93362 27.10818 42.47611 24.06939 47.83653
2016.2788       43.48419 34.70294 54.48554 30.79643 61.39408
2016.2815       39.98677 31.87798 50.15641 28.27360 56.54775
2016.2843       38.99057 31.05229 48.95645 27.52649 55.22451
2016.2870       39.33681 31.29620 49.44140 27.72777 55.80155
```

What do these dates mean?

I do not understand what 2514,2541 means.

How can I get a normal date format?

```
ts <- structure(list(Date = structure(1:13, .Label = c("01.04.2012", 
"02.04.2012", "03.04.2012", "04.04.2012", "05.04.2012", "06.04.2012", 
"07.04.2012", "08.04.2012", "09.04.2012", "10.04.2012", "11.04.2012", 
"12.04.2012", "13.04.2012"), class = "factor"), Daily.admissions = c(49L, 
58L, 36L, 44L, 64L, 46L, 46L, 39L, 58L, 61L, 51L, 52L, 48L)), .Names = c("Date", 
"Daily.admissions"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a decimal date.

You can't change it's representation in `sp` object, but you can convert it manually for investigation:

```
library(lubridate)
times <- as.vector(time(sp$mean))
sapply(times, function(x) { format(date_decimal(x), "%Y-%m-%d") })
# [1] "2012-04-14" "2012-04-15" "2012-04-16" "2012-04-17" "2012-04-18" "2012-04-19" "2012-04-20" "2012-04-21"
# [9] "2012-04-22" "2012-04-23" "2012-04-24" "2012-04-25" "2012-04-26" "2012-04-27"
```